# How to keep a flex container all in one page without scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am creating a web page which needs has to display some movie covers all in a single page, without scrolling it, becouse it will be on display. the problem is that i want to get the content to resize instead of making the web page scrollable. I also need to support n movies (they are dependent). I've tried using flexbox twice, but it doesnt work. Also, I am using tailwindcss framework, but i don't think that's a problem as it is just css in form of classes...

```html
<html class='h-full m-0 p-0'>
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@next/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class='h-full m-0 p-0'>
  <div class='mx-10 mt-10 flex content-center items-center'>
    <div class='flex flex-wrap'>
<!-- iterate over every movie -->
      <div class='m-2 relative flex-grow h-full' style='flex-basis: 20%'>
        <span class='px-2 py-1 rounded-full bg-blue-500 text-white absolute z-0' style='top: -0.5rem; right: -0.5rem'>0</span>
         <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525604803468-3064e402d70c' class: 'w-full' />
         <span class='w-full opacity-75 bg-black text-white py-1 absolute z-0 inset-x-0 bottom-0 text-center px-2'>title</span>
      </div>
<!-- end -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I added a the full example (with an example image take from unsplash) of what i want it to look like.

Comment: So, you want the covers to shrink or grow to fill the screen, but never be bigger than the screen so you don't have to scroll vertically or horizontally? Do you know the ratio of the covers and the screen? Are they always the same?

Comment: no, they can differ, but they will be mostly 16:9 for the screen and 27″ x 40″ for the poster i think. but as i sad, they could differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do what you are asking without JavaScript. In the following example, I used CSS to maintain the ratio of the covers, and used JavaScript to calculate the maximum width that would keep the content from scrolling vertically.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/j9ryza7t/100/).

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

let numCovers = 10;
let coverList = document.querySelector(".cover-list");

// this function determines what percentage of the cover-list's width
// each cover should take up. It will maximize how large they can be
// without making the total grid size larger than cover-list.
// This should prevent scrolling.
function getBasis() {
  let ratio = 1.35; // height/width
  let width = coverList.clientWidth;
  let height = coverList.clientHeight;
  
  // this loop is really slow, you may want to find a faster way
  let col = 0;
  let accWidth, accHeight, numRows;
  do {
   col++;
    if (col > numCovers) {
     // maximize height
      return (height / ratio) + "px";
    }
   accWidth = width / col;
    accHeight = accWidth * ratio;
    numRows = Math.ceil(numCovers / col);
  } while (accHeight * numRows > height);
  
  return (100 / col) + "%";
}

function generateCovers() {
 // clear existing covers
  coverList.innerHTML = "";
  let basis = getBasis();
  for (let i = 0; i < numCovers; i++) {
    let cover = document.createElement("div");
    cover.classList.add("cover");
    cover.style.flexBasis = basis;
    let inner = document.createElement("div");
    inner.classList.add("inner");
    inner.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    cover.append(inner);
    coverList.append(cover);
  }
}

let numCoversInput = document.querySelector("#num-covers");
numCoversInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
 numCovers = Math.min(Math.max(this.value, 1), 500);
  this.value = numCovers;
  generateCovers();
});
generateCovers();

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  let basis = getBasis();
  coverList.querySelectorAll(".cover").forEach(function(el) {
   el.style.flexBasis = basis;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  /* set margin to computable value for cover-list calcs */
  margin: 5px;
}

#controls {
  height: 25px;
}

.cover-list {
  /* account for margin and controls with calc */
  width: calc(100vw - 10px);
  height: calc(100vh - 35px);
  
  /* use flex so the content will wrap as desired */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
}

.inner {
  /* padding percentages are based on width, so setting
     the height to 0 and padding-bottom to a percentage
     allows us to maintain a ratio */
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 135%;
}
```

```html
<div id="controls">
  <label>
    Number of covers: <input id="num-covers" type="number" value="10" min="1" max="500"/>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="cover-list">
</div>
```

Comment: this is actually awsome, thank you very much! but i cant get it work with other elements to in the cover div (like the two spans and the img).. Have you got any advice? (Maybe it's just me...)

Comment: also, it seems like that by adding just a little bit of margin or padding to the covers it breaks...

Comment: You will want to just add your elements inside the `.cover` elements. I don't know how you are styling the two spans and img, but you want to make sure that they are staying inside of the cover. If they expand larger than it, then it will ruin the calculation being done in JavaScript. The easiest thing to do would be to make the content fit its parent, or just set `overflow:hidden` on the cover.

To add padding, you will want to add it to the children of the cover, or set `box-sizing:border-box` on the cover.